# Class module to object, standard module

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping for someone who can actually guide me with the procedure. I working on something that is similar to the below code.

The problem is,  I dont know what it means by,
(The code must be in an object instead of a module to work.)

How do you call a class module in the standard module? Or How does the code works? I mean, i do understand the function but how to execute the below? Thanks guys. Apologies for my ignorance.

```
        Option Explicit

Public WithEvents IE1 As InternetExplorer
Public IE2 As InternetExplorer


Private Sub Automation()

Dim objElement As Object
Dim objButton As Object
Dim objLink As Object
Dim objLink2 As Object
Dim mytextfield1 As Object
Dim mytextfield2 As Object

Set IE1 = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set IE2 = Nothing

With IE1
.navigate "***website url***"
.Visible = True  'allows for viewing the web page
While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set mytextfield1 = .document.all.Item("txtUserName")
    mytextfield1.Value = "***username***"
    Set mytextfield2 = .document.all.Item("txtPassword")
    mytextfield2.Value = "***password***"
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    IE1.document.getElementById("Submit").Click
End With

    ' loop until the page finishes loading
Do While IE1.Busy: Loop

 'Opens another link
 With IE1
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 IE1.navigate "***url***"
 End With

 'Opens the menu
 With IE1
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 IE1.navigate "***URL in frame***", ["left"]
 End With

 'Opens the Profile search menu
 With IE1
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 IE1.navigate "***url in another frame***", , ["mainParent"]
 End With

 'Copies the ID# from the Excel worksheet and pastes it to search in site to search
 With IE1
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
 Set objElement = .document.frames("mainParent").document.frames("main1").document.forms("AgentIdentificationNumberSearch").document.getElementById("IDN")
 objElement.Value = Sheets("Appointments").Range("a2").Value
 Set objButton = .document.frames("mainParent").document.frames("main1").document.forms("AgentIdentificationNumberSearch").document.getElementById("Search")
 objButton.Click
 End With

 'Clicks "View Profile Summary" and opens new window
 With IE1
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
 Set objLink = IE1.document.frames("mainParent").document.forms("AgentProfileList").document.getElementById("grdProfile_r_0").document.getElementsByTagName("a")(1)
 objLink.Click
 End With

 'Ensure new window has been created (if the window does not generate, this will go on forever)
 Do While IE2 Is Nothing: Loop
 Do While IE2.Busy: Loop

'Click first link in the new window
 With IE2
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
 Set objLink2 = IE2.document.forms("form1").document.getElementsByTagName("a")(2)
 objLink2.Click
 End With

 Set IE2 = Nothing

End Sub

________________________

Private Sub IE1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set IE2 = New InternetExplorer
    Set ppDisp = IE2.Application
    Debug.Print "NewWindow2"
 End Sub
```

Comment: where does it say "The code must be in an object instead of a module to work"?
I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Are you familiar with object oriented programming?

Comment: You can't use WithEvents in a regular module - you need to structure your code (or that part of it) in a class module.

Comment: Hi Tim, simply the answer I need. Thanks for pointing that out. If its ok, Can you show me a start on how to call the code from a class module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do you call a class module in the standard module?*

You do it all the time without even realizing. `Range` is a class, `Workbook` is a class too, as is `Worksheet` and `Application`. The only difference is that you're not the one *creating* these objects.

So move that code to a new *class module*, and make the procedure `Public` so that the class' *default interface* exposes that member. This could be an opportunity to rename the procedure so that it looks like a *verb* rather than a *noun*. Keep nouns for module names and properties, and use verbs for methods/procedures: they *do* something; classes/objects *are* something.

Keep these fields `Private`, they are implementation details that have no business being `Public`:

> ```
> Public WithEvents IE1 As InternetExplorer
> Public IE2 As InternetExplorer
> ```

You'll want to create a `New` *instance* of that class module, from a standard one - say you kept the default `Class1` name for the class, and renamed the procedure to `RunAutomation`, your standard module might look like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With New Class1
        .RunAutomation
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the response Math. Will try With New Class1
    .RunAutomation
End With to a new module

Comment: @ChrisLacs alternatively you can `Dim myObject As Class1` then do `Set myObject = New Class1` and then `myObject.RunAutomation`, but since that's all it needs to do, yielding the object reference to a `With` block removes the need to declare and initialize a local variable for it.

Comment: This is noted. Thanks again for being nice.